# How to call any variable in the citrus bean configuration class from citrus test class

Tags: java, citrus-framework

I have to use my username and password in citrus bean configuration class, and those values I have set in my test class in an string variable. 
So how I can call those in configuration class as configuration class runs by default.

// I have my test class as below
   // Citrus test class

```
@Test
public class IntegrationTest extends TestNGCitrusTestRunner {

@CitrusTest()
    public void demoTest() {    

    variable("userName", System.getenv("UName"));
    variable("password", System.getenv("Password"));

    http(actionBuilder -> actionBuilder
                        .client("someclient")
                        .send()
                        .post()
                        .path("/token")
                        .messageType(MessageType.PLAINTEXT)
                        .payload("some load")
                        );

    http(actionBuilder -> actionBuilder
                        .client("someclient")
                        .receive()
                        .response()
                        .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
                        .extractFromPayload("$.token","accessToken")
                        .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                        );
    }
}

//citrus configuration class

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
public class CitrusConfig {

private String proxyUser = "";
private string proxyPassword = "";
```

// in the above variable how I can call those username and password I set in my test class.

```
@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword));
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some code examples what you have done.

Comment: I have added some code samples above.